# Dynamic Named Range for Dropdown: Removing Duplicates without VBA

Tags: excel

I am creating an Excel dashboard that I want to be as "hands-off" as possible.

Users paste in an exported .csv report that looks like the below, can have up to tens of thousands of rows:

```
Company     Property    Segment Type    Date        Forecast
Company 1   Property 1  Transient       01/01/2016  395.6599731
Company 1   Property 1  Corporate       01/01/2016  5066.720295
Company 1   Property 2  Transient       01/01/2016  4671.060322
Company 1   Property 2  Corporate       01/01/2016  0
Company 1   Property 1  Transient       02/01/2016  3513.280067
Company 1   Property 1  Corporate       02/01/2016  3513.280067
Company 1   Property 2  Transient       02/01/2016  0
Company 1   Property 2  Corporate       02/01/2016  3180.830109
Company 2   Property 1  Transient       01/01/2016  3180.830109
Company 2   Property 1  Corporate       01/01/2016  749.5098877
Company 2   Property 2  Transient       01/01/2016  3104.579819
Company 2   Property 2  Corporate       01/01/2016  2355.069931
Company 2   Property 1  Transient       02/01/2016  602.5899658
Company 2   Property 1  Corporate       02/01/2016  3327.980011
Company 2   Property 2  Transient       02/01/2016  2725.390045
Company 2   Property 2  Corporate       02/01/2016  0
```

There will be a separate tab containing a Company dropdown list, a Property dropdown list, and Average Forecast displays.

I've got multiple dynamic named ranges as follows (sample is for Companies):

=OFFSET(Data!$A$2, 0, 0, COUNTA(Data!$A:$A)-1, 1)

I want to have dropdowns that do not contain duplicates, so just Company 1, Company 2.

When I use the dynamic named range above, the dropdown has 8 Company 1s and 8 Company 2s.

Any way to do this without using VBA?  Can Array functions be nested within Dynamic Named Ranges?

Comment: One quick way, if you can add columns, is to add a helper column somewhere (or just add to a blank one). Then, copy all the companies in column A (just activate cell `A2`, and press CTRL+SHIFT+[down arrow]), then use the built-in "Remove Duplicates" function, and then just use that for your drop down.  Would that work?

Comment: It would be easier if you use a helper column (Additional column).

Comment: Hi Bruce:  basically, I want them to be able to just paste it in directly, and then have everything auto-populate.  So want to avoid Remove Duplicates etc if at all possible.  Would there be a way to have a helper column populate automatically on a data page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create pivot tables to make a list of unique values for each dropdown. Use the Data sheet as the source and the corresponding dropdown field as the pivot table row field. Each pivot table will be a list of the unique values for that field.

Then use your offset formula on the pivot table ranges rather than the Data ranges to create your named range for the data validation. The only drawback is the pivot tables will need refreshed when new data is pasted.

Comment: Hi bws1999:  yes, wanting to avoid having the user have to do anything except for paste in the data (including not having to refresh a pivot table).